# Tabbing through options with react-select

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using **react-select** for my dropdowns, and I want to be able to tab through the options in the dropdown.
Does anyone know if this is possible? I can not find anything about this in their documentation: [react-select](https://react-select.com/home)

Comment: Out of the box you can use the up and down arrow keys to navigate between options. Will that work? Or do you need it to be the tab key?